# Puppeteer - Get a page object from the 'browser.pages()' array?

Tags: tabs, popup, puppeteer

During testing, a link that is clicked on could open in a new tab. I would like to get that page object, bring it to the front, and then take screenshots of it.

How do I get the page object of the last page in the pages array?

```
const pages = await browser.pages()
const newPage = pages[-1]
await newPage.bringToFront()
```

I am getting the error:

`ReferenceError: newPage is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-1` arrays index is not valid in JavaScript so to get the last element you can do the following:

```js
const pages = await browser.pages()
const newPage = pages[pages.length - 1];
await newPage.bringToFront()
```